# Google Image Search via Upload

Tags: image, search

The image search API from Google has been depreciated:
https://developers.google.com/image-search/

My question is where can we now get the same data? It says it has moved to the new Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), but I cannot find where to now submit uploaded image data for the search. Can someone please explain or link me the information for this.

Our web app needs to be able to upload the image to google and check via a API where the image has been found.

Also if Google does not allow this is there any substitutes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get search result using direct link for uploaded image.

let direct link be http://i47.tinypic.com/ekepuq.png (to stream image data for search) then Make url as

"http ://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=[diretlink]"

ie " http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://i47.tinypic.com/ekepuq.png " and can get search result for the same image.