# Google similar image search API

Tags: image, api, search

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to do google similar image searches via an API?

I know the image search api is depreciated but is it still useable? 
https://developers.google.com/image-search/

Also... It seems that you can do image searches with the custom search api but I can't seem to work out if a similar image search is possible.
http://thenextweb.com/dd/2012/02/14/googles-custom-search-api-now-supports-image-only-results/

Any leads on advice on working this our would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i wrote code using python to download  full resolution images from google  follow this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28487500/2875380 i hope this helps u

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a URL for a hosted image (using Dropbox, imgur, etc), the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134958/116891 shows you how to find similar images. Basically,

```
http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=YOUR_HOSTED_URL
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the list of similar image in JSON format?

Comment: The direct link is useful, but I agree with W.K.S we need a way to get a text response. Something like what https://www.mashape.com/imagesearcher/camfind would return.

Comment: is there any way to post that image manually instead of url and with postrequest for json response
?

Answer (score 0):

That is deprecated.
But I need JSON format of similar images result.
So, I try to use google cse but this is not supported searching of similar images.
It's just displayed image search results in a custom domain.

Another method that i try is URL.

> http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=YOUR_HOSTED_URL

But this is not solution what i need.
It is because able to use in the browser. I need JSON.

Conclude, I decide to use Vision API of Google.
This is very simple.

> https://cloud.google.com/vision/

You can try on the top.

1. First, access the URL.
2. Second, upload your image file on the "Try API".
3. Third, click "JSON" tab menu on the result.

You can be seen JSON about similar images.